# What are the prototypes for these flex functions in a re-entrant parser?

Tags: flex-lexer

I'm converting a working flex/bison parser to run re-entrantly.  The parser has the ability to  accept `include command-file.txt` directives, which was implemented on the flex side of things like this:

```
^include            {   BEGIN INCL;             }
<INCL>{ws}+         {   /* Ignore */            }
<INCL>[^ \t\n\r\f]+ {   /* Swallow everything up to whitespace or an EOL character.
                         * When state returns to initial, the whitepsace
                         * and/or EOL will be taken care of. */
                        yyin = fopen ( yytext, "r" );
                        if (! yyin) {
                            char filename[1024];
                            sprintf(filename,"/home/scripts/%s",yytext);
                            yyin = fopen( filename, "r");
                            if ( ! yyin) {
                                char buf[256];
                                sprintf(buf,"Couldn't open ""%s"".",yytext);
                                yyerror(buf);
                            }
                        }
                        yypush_buffer_state(yy_create_buffer(yyin, YY_BUF_SIZE));
                        BEGIN 0;
                    }
<<EOF>>             {
                        yypop_buffer_state();
                        if (!YY_CURRENT_BUFFER) {
                                yyterminate();
                        }
                    }
```

This works nicely.  Now that I've added `%option reentrant` and `%option bison-bridge`, I get these errors:

```
lexer.l:119: error: too few arguments to function `yy_create_buffer'
lexer.l:119: error: too few arguments to function `yypush_buffer_state'
lexer.l:123: error: too few arguments to function `yypop_buffer_state'
```

***What are the proper ways to invoke these functions/macros in a re-entrant parser?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reentrant interfaces are documented (briefly) in the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Extra-Reentrant-Argument.html).

All interfaces have one extra argument of type `yyscan_t` which comes at the end of the argument list. Examples (pulled from a flex-generated file):

```
YY_BUFFER_STATE yy_create_buffer (FILE *file,int size ,yyscan_t yyscanner );
void yy_delete_buffer (YY_BUFFER_STATE b ,yyscan_t yyscanner );
void yy_flush_buffer (YY_BUFFER_STATE b ,yyscan_t yyscanner );
void yypush_buffer_state (YY_BUFFER_STATE new_buffer ,yyscan_t yyscanner );
void yypop_buffer_state (yyscan_t yyscanner );
```

`yylex` follows the same pattern, so you can use `yyscanner` inside an action to refer to the argument provided to `yylex`